# Access value that promise .then returns outside of promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, react-redux

Title says it all, I am using the [async-library](https://github.com/caolan/async) `eachSeries` method

```
let 
  valueOne = null,
  validItem = null;

const asyncEachSeries = require('async/eachSeries');

const getContent = function (item) {
  contentResponse = fetchContent(item);
  return contentResponse;
}

if (recommendationsArr.length > 0) {
  asyncEachSeries(recommendationsArr, function (item, callback) {
    getApiContent(item).then(function getValidResult(response) {
      try { 
        valueOne = response.content.valueOne || null; //may or may not be present
        recommendationsArr.splice(recommendationsArr.indexOf(item), 1); 
        validItem = item;
        console.log("##### valueOne is: ", valueOne); // I get data here
        return true;
      } catch (err) {
        valueOne = null;
        return false;
      }
    });
    //I am guessing I need a return statement here, though not sure what
  });

  console.log("##### Outside promise, valueOne is: ", valueOne); // no data here

  // Access valueOne, validItem, recommendationsArr to be able to pass as props for the component 
  return {
    component: <Layout><ComponentName
      //pass other non-dependent props
      validItem={validItem}
      valueOne={valueOne}
      recommendationsArr={recommendationsArr}
    /></Layout>,
    title: `Page Title`,
  };
}

return null;
```

Scenario: `recommendationsArr` is an array of items (Its 99.9% not null, but since its an external api call I prefer to have a check). The purpose is to have values for `valueOne`, `validItem`, and an updated `recommendationsArr`.
The validity depends on the existence of `valueOne`, so if the `recommendationsArr[0]` has valid `valueOne` then I don't need to fetch api results for the rest of the array. I am using `eachSeries` as it runs only a single async operation at a time, hence if that async gets me the valid result I don't have to iterate over other items.

Sample recommendationsArr: `recommendationsArr = ["blue", "white", "green", "red"]; //usually the array is anywhere between 12-50 elements`

Now in order to be able to pass the updated values to the component I need to be able to access the values set in `try` block outside of the `asyncEachSeries` iteration loop. I understand I will have to `return` the processed/new values but am not sure at what point and how to return those values.

Comment: do you initialize valueOne with `var` anywhere? If not, try putting  `var valueOne;` above the promise

Comment: you can't expect `valueOne` to have a value at that point because asynchronous code is asynchronous - no amount of returns will help

Comment: Not sure about async, but bluebirds [`.mapSeries`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) will resolve an array of values.

Comment: @fredrover I do, I have a `let` above the promise, just updated the question

Comment: @Matt I am not sure if I understand what you mean, I am able to iterate through the array the challenge is to access the values outside the promise

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand, but is there a way that I can update a var value and access that outside? Will I lose any value I save in the variables outside of the `Promise`?

Comment: Don't use `async.js` callbacks with promises.

Comment: What do you suggest then? How can I achieve the solution without using the async.js

Answer (score 0):

As is usual with any question concerning asynchronous code you return values by using the `callback`. But `eachSeries` does not collect return values. What you want is `async.mapSeries`:

```
async.mapSeries(recommendationsArr, function (item, callback) {
  getApiContent(item).then(function (response) {
    try { 
      valueOne = response.content.valueOne || null; //may or may not be present
      recommendationsArr.splice(recommendationsArr.indexOf(item), 1); 
      validItem = item;
      callback(null, valueOne); // This is how you return a value
      // return true; // return does absolutely nothing
    } catch (err) {
      valueOne = null;
      callback(err, valueOne);
      // return false;
    }
  });
},function (err, result) {
  // this is where you can process the result
  // note that the result is an array
});
```

However, since you are using promises you can use `async-q` instead which wraps caolan's async library in promises:

```
var asyncQ = require('async-q');

asyncQ.mapSeries(recommendationsArr, function (item) {
  // Note: the return in the line below is important
  return getApiContent(item).then(function (response) {
    try { 
      valueOne = response.content.valueOne || null; //may or may not be present
      recommendationsArr.splice(recommendationsArr.indexOf(item), 1); 
      validItem = item;
      return valueOne; // this is how you return a value in a promise
    } catch (err) {
      return null
    }
  });
})
.then(function(result) {
  // you can process the result here
});
```

Personally I'd prefer to rewrite the code and process the results at the end because the code is cleaner:

```
asyncQ.mapSeries(recommendationsArr, getApiContent)
  .then(function (result) {
    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
      var response = result[i];
      // do what needs to be done with each response here
    }
  });
```

Comment: `asyncQ.mapSeries` is not synchronous, the reason am using async-library `eachSeries` method as it runs only a single async operation at a time, since I don't need to loop through the entire array I only care about the first best match, how can I achieve that with `mapSeries` ?

Comment: mapSeries is exactly the same as eachSeries except that the final callback also gets passed the final result of the operations. Read the documentation

Comment: @user988544: `async.eachSeries` will loop through the entire array

Comment: @user988544: Perhaps it's better to explain what you think you want to do rather than what you think is wrong with your code